# Google apps script custom drive search latency

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a Google site set up, using a custom search engine as detailed in [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/other-examples/advanced-search-on-google-sites#TOC-TUTORIAL) to be able to search for files in Drive. One problem I had with this setup is that it doesn't appear to be able to search recursively. So I hit up the [Developers Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) and modified it a bit to be able to do this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var folderIterator = folders.next();
    var results = folderIterator.searchFiles('fullText contains "' + e.parameter.q + '"');
    while(results.hasNext()) {
      var file = results.next();
      panel.add(app.createAnchor(file.getName(), file.getUrl()));
    } 
  }
  var scrollPanel = app.createScrollPanel(panel).setHeight(200);
  app.add(scrollPanel);

  return app;
}
```

The problem is, the original solution (folder-specific) takes about 1 minute to return. The recursive solution (searches for all files a user has access to) can take up to 2 minutes. Any ideas how we can optimize this to return in, say, 10 seconds or less? Given that we're talking on the order of less than 200 files, this feels like it should be totally doable given Google's search prowess. Is this unreasonable?

Comment: `UiApp` is deprecated.   Use HTML Service.

Comment: I don't think that you need to get the folders, then search for files in each folder.  `getFiles()` gets all files in the users drive, no matter what folder they are in.  [Google Documentation - Search Files](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams)  The `search` returns a FileIterator.

Comment: This got me back on track! By replacing UiApp with HtmlService, the search speed increased to my expectation. 

The reason behind trying to enumerate folders was that `DriveApp.getFolderById('blah').searchFiles('blah')` seems to only search the immediate folder. To get around this, I asked the team to consolidate files to a single folder. It works beautifully now -- but is there another way to be able to search recursively, beginning with a specified folder? Another issue is that I appear to be unable to modify a published app - I have to start fresh every time. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can publish new versions of a web app.  File, Manage Versions, and save a new version.  Or you can save a new version right in the "Deploy as Web App" Dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary motive of my question was around latency -- custom drive search taking too long as a web app in a Google site. Credit goes to Sandy Good for pointing out that `UiApp is deprecated. Use HTML Service.`. If you'd post this as an answer, I'm happy to mark that :)

After moving all the contents to a single folder in drive, here's what I came up with:

```
// rewrite
function doGet(e) {
  var results = DriveApp.getFolderById('<drive id here>').searchFiles('fullText contains "' + e.parameter.q + '"');
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Results: <br /><br /><ul>');
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var file = results.next();
    output.append('<li><a href="' + file.getUrl() + '">' + file.getName() + '</a></li>');
  }
  output.append('</ul>');
  return output;
}
```

Comment: For future seekers of this knowledge, I was contacted recently by Google Support letting me know that HTMLService Native/Emulated modes are deprecated, and to see [this post for the recommended IFrame Solution](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/iframe?utm_campaign=app%20invites_deprication_google_apps_script_101315&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog).